# Exclude files / dirs logrotate

Tags: linux, logrotate

I am logging all our applications logs to /logs/, where all our applications have an seperate directory. I have made a custom logrotate file as follows:

```
/logs/*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 1
    sharedscripts
    dateext
}
```

So this is catching all logfiles within /logs. But i want to leave some directories out of the rotation. Can I somehow exclude these directories? And what would be the best practice in this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [recommended location](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARLOGLOGFILESANDDIRECTORIES) for log files is `/var/log`.

You can do some file globbing and multiple filespecs to specify what to include:

```
/var/log/appone.log
/var/log/app[2-7].log
/var/log/other*.log
{
    log options
}
```

but it's better to create different files for each app and put them in `/etc/logrotate.d` and include only one or two filespecs in each that are associated in some way (e.g. app or function/purpose). Use the existing files in that directory as models.

Answer (score 0):

Use wildcards sparingly. If I were you, I'd specify the logfiles of each application separately.

Answer (score 0):

Short of doing evil glob syntax I don't think there's any obvious way.

The best way would be to switch to a conf file per app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use globbing to do this: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/en/man7/glob.7.html